# How can i solve this error ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses')

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

from dataclasses import dataclass i'm running this code in vs code for a project but it will give the
error like (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses')

After i getting this error i'm making pip install dataclasses then also it give same error please help me to run this code in vs code.

[I'm facing this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRFnE.png)

Comment: What version of python are you running? Run this code `import sys; print(sys.version_info)`